# Elasticsearch custom_filters_score not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to test with custom_filters_scores in elasticsearch but even the most basic versions are producing errors. Can anyone point out why the following error message is occurring?

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filters": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "Price": {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 200
              }
           }
         }
       }
     ],
   }
}
```

The error is as follows:

```
nested: QueryParsingException[[index] No query registered for [custom_filters_score]]; }]", "status": 400
```

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using???

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using elasticsearch 1.x that has a new query that handles all the different boosting usecases. It's called `function_score` and it replaced the `custom_filters_score` in 1.0, already deprecated since `0.90.4`.

Have a look at the [documentation page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), it's quite extensive and contains at the bottom of the page examples on how to migrate from previously available queries to `function_score`.

Comment: Hi @javanna - Do you mind looking into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37372951/elasticsearch-query-time-boosting-produces-result-in-inadequate-order?noredirect=1#comment62264775_37372951) of mine please?